# the window is not getting closed by clicking on 'X' button

Tags: java

The window is not getting closed by clicking on 'X' button.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class HowdyWindow extends Frame{
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        new HowdyWindow();
    }

    HowdyWindow(){
        Label label;
        label = new Label("Howdy!");
        add(label);
        pack();
        show();
    }

    public void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent event) {
        if(event.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)
            System.exit();
    }
}
```

Please help me in rectifying this issue. Being a beginner, I don't understand why I am getting this behaviour.

Comment: Were you able to review the answers yet?

Answer (score 1):

**Some remarks**

So, there's still a lot wrong with your code.

- `System.exit()` needs an exitCode:

  System.exit(0);
- `WindowEvents` will only be captured, if your add a *listener* to your frame
- AWT is not the best choice to start Java UI Developing. Swing (`JFrame` instead of `Frame`) might be a better choice.
- <strike>`show()`</strike> is deprecated. Use `setVisible(true)` instead.
- Use `{ }` even for one-line `if()`s. It's easier to read and *safer* if at any time you add functionality.

**Basic Corrections**

Consider this corrected version:

```
public class HowdyWindow extends Frame {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new HowdyWindow();
    }

    HowdyWindow() {
        Label label;
        label = new Label("Howdy!");
        add(label);
        pack();
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                processWindowEvent(e);
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent event) {
        if (event.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tie your closing-Method to the UI-element (here your HowdyWindow). In java you can achieve this by using certain Listeners: Have a look at this tutorial to get a better understanding https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html

However, to work with your code one solution might be:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class HowdyWindow extends Frame{
    public static void main(String arg[]){
    new HowdyWindow();
}
HowdyWindow() {
    Label label;
    label = new Label("Howdy!");
    add(label);
    pack();
    show();
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            processWindowEvent(e);
        }
    });

}
public void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent event) {
    if(event.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)
        System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Besides, your code was not compiling because of the `System.exit();`

Answer (score -2):

Try this code -

```
JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
```

And make slight modifications to your Event code -

```
 public void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent event) {

        if (event.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
            switch(defaultCloseOperation) {
              ...
          case EXIT_ON_CLOSE:
                  // This needs to match the checkExit call in
                  // setDefaultCloseOperation
        System.exit(0);
        break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not a JFrame in sight here. Switch not necessary. Break after System.exit () ?!  Listener nevet added...